# ISO C90 Error: Declarations

Tags: c, declaration

First of all let me say that this standard is required and is what I have to use currently.

Anyways, I am getting one error and tried moving my FILE * blocks all over, inside/outside main, before executables, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Initialize vars */
char c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12;

int main()
{

    /* Open encrypted.txt for reading */
FILE *enc;
enc = fopen("encrypted.txt", "r");

    /* Retrieve individual characters, displace by 4 letters (decryption method) */
c1 = (getc(enc))-4;
c2 = (getc(enc))-4;
c3 = (getc(enc))-4;
c4 = (getc(enc))-4;
c5 = (getc(enc))-4;
c6 = (getc(enc))-4;
c7 = (getc(enc))-4;
c8 = (getc(enc))-4;
c9 = (getc(enc))-4;
c10 = (getc(enc))-4;
c11 = (getc(enc))-4;
c12 = (getc(enc))-4;

    /* Display resulting decrypted message */
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", (char)c1, (char)c2, (char)c3, (char)c4, (char)c5, (char)c6, (char)c7, (char)c8, (char)c9, (char)c10, (char)c11, (char)c12);

    /* Write decrypted message to new file named "decrypted" */
FILE *dec;
dec = fopen("decrypted", "w");

fprintf(dec,"%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", (char)c1, (char)c2, (char)c3, (char)c4, (char)c5, (char)c6, (char)c7, (char)c8, (char)c9, (char)c10, (char)c11, (char)c12);

    /* Close files */
fclose(enc);
fclose(dec);

}
```

Any tips on how to get rid of this error are appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C90 doesn't permit variable declarations after other statements in a block, so you need to declare dec at the top alongside where you declare enc:

```
int main()
{

    /* Open encrypted.txt for reading */
   FILE *enc, *dec;
   ...
}
```

Comment: That was exactly it. I never even thought of that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In C99 you can declare after other statements and inside for loop. But not in C90

if you use gcc ,use -std=c99 option to avoid this error.

```
 gcc -std=c99 -Wall source.c
```

Or

move `FILE *dec;` to the down of `FILE *enc;`

Like this

```
 FILE *enc;
 FILE *dec;
```